# Advices for 1.5m files syncing with rsync

Tags: backup, rsync

I have a folder with about 1.5 million files and I need them to be copied to a secondary server as often as possible. What would you recommend because clearly standard rsync commands do not make it because just sending the incremental file list (while using rsync -Pcr options) takes about 30 minutes... and the file transfer about 10 seconds. How would you solve this issue fellow SysAdmins?

I currently use the following command with a 30 minute interval:

```
rsync -Pcr /var/primary/storage /var/secondary/ --log-file=/tmp/rsync.log
```

Note: The /var/primary/storage is a folder mounted to the secondary server via NFS

UPDATE:

I've also tried now the following command:

```
cp -aur /var/primary/storage /var/secondary/
```

But it is odd for me that the command asks me if I allow the overwriting of a destination file that has the exact same modified date as the source file. Isn't the update option supposed to watch it and copy by default if a source file is newer (or modified) than the destination file?

Comment: "As often as possible" sounds a lot like "instant". If yes, I'd go for something like [SDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_storage) or [DRBD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Replicated_Block_Device)

Comment: Or ZFS with send/receive  if it doesn't need to be all that instant (but still a lot faster then rsync)

Comment: I use [Reslio Sync](https://www.resilio.com/) for syncing files between computers, either in the same building or across the world. 1.5 million files is pretty extreme, but it's worth a shot. Just leave it running on both machines. It's not free for business

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, however it is a bit complicated and needs some thinking. If you don't want to read it, then **TLDR: No NFS, no issue and it is better to give than get**

So I've tried to sync the files from FileServer-1 to FileServer-2. To ease up the stress on FileServer-1, I was thinking I could execute the rsync command on FileServer-2 and copy the files from FileServer-1. I've reversed it and ran the rsync command from the FileServer-1 to copy the folders incremental filelist to FileServer-2.Magic happened, it was faster. Still unacceptable, but faster.

After a while I had to unmount an NFS folder from both FileServers. By accident I ran  the rsync command from FileServer-1 to copy the files from local machine to FileServer-2. Now the real miracle happened because it was done in about 2 minutes.

I've deleted about ~600MB of data from FileServer-2 and started rsync again just to see how much time does rsync need to copy all the files (that is about 10.000 files). It took less than 5 minutes !!!!

Ever since I have the folders unmounted (that have nothing to do with the files I'm trying to rsync) rsync started working like a beast.

Anyone has an explanation how come Rsync and NFS heates eachother like this? Or this is just a very unique phenomenon on my systems? Using CentOS 7, I've forgot to tell that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best bet is actually monitoring or logging which files have changed. Even though this could be solved using a SDS, since you're using rsync I suggest you're using a normal filesystem.

Therefore, I think running `inotifywait` as a deamon is the best bet for you:

```
sudo inotifywait --daemon --outfile /tmp/fschanges --recursive /path/to/watch \
  --event modify --event move --event create --event delete --event close_write
```

When embedding this in a simple bash script that 1) reads the file, 2) pushes the changes and 3) clears the contents when done, you should get a pretty 'instant' solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
logfile="/tmp/fschanges"
path="/home/roy/Downloads"

# Stop deamon upon exit
trap "killall inotifywait" EXIT

# Init deamon
inotifywait --daemon --outfile $logfile --recursive $path \
      --event modify --event move --event create --event delete --event close_write &

while true; do
  # Loop trough file
  while read change; do
    srcpath=$(echo "$change" | cut -d' ' -f1)
    action=$(echo "$change" | cut -d' ' -f2)
    file=$(echo "$change" | cut -d' ' -f3)

    if [[ $action == *"DELETE"* ]]; then
      echo "DELETE: rsync $srcpath$file"
    elif [[ $action == *"CREATE"* ]]; then
      echo "CREATE: rsync $srcpath$file"
    elif [[ $action == *"WRITE"* ]]; then
      echo "WRITE: rsync $srcptah$file"
    fi
  done < $logfile

  # Clear the log
  > $logfile

  # Allow for cooldown
  sleep 1
done
```

Off-course the script above needs to be properly completed, but you get the general idea.

Comment: I think this is almost exactly the same what I've tried yesterday with this: https://github.com/splitbrain/Watcher This wasn't looking bad, however just starting up crashed the whole script because of the amount of files. I'll give the script a try (mainly because I like scripts) and I hope it will work.

Comment: Also: What if I just create a standard service from it?

Comment: Simply add the required headers (for example see watcher.py in your Github project) and it'll run as a service. Finally, `inotifywait` runs on kernel level, therefore I give it better chances of not crashing (although I don't know enough about Python to know how that runs).

Comment: It didn't work, it just took too long. However, the solution was very strange, I'll write it down in a sec as an answer.

Comment: [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450537/rsync-over-nfs-inconsistent-speed) explains it all. I simply overlooked that it was an NFS. By omitting the `-z` flag (disabling compression) you should get better performance. Also, I wonder if the `-x` flag improves speeds…